# Java, Сортировка нескольких списков через Collections.sort()

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции

Добрый день, у меня появилась необходимость отсортировать список чисел по убыванию, я бы воспользовался Collections.sort(), но к моему списку привязаны еще 2 таких-же типа String, т.е. (допустим) если взять со всех списков индекс 0, то получиться что-то типа "У Марины через " "45" " дней годовщина", и мне нужно отсортировать средний список по убыванию так, что-бы остальные списки находились в том же индексе. Подскажите, можно ли это реализовать через Collections.sort()?
Сортировкой обмена думаю будет долговато т.к. в списке более 9 тыс. значений.

Comment: Нет. В чистом виде (из коробки) Collections.sort() вам не поможет. (9 тыс. элементов не так много. Посмотрите алгоритмы быстрой сортировки и в их реализации добавьте соответствующие обмены на другие списки)

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то у вас есть 3 ArrayList , которые связаны между собой совпадающими индексами и вы хотите просто отсортировать одну коллекцию. но при этом не утратить связь с другими элементами?